# Hibernate Post Commit Update event not always firing as expected

Tags: hibernate, grails, listener

In the application I work on we have a listener that implements PostInsertEventListener, PostUpdateEventListener and PostDeleteEventListener. This listener is then attached to these events POST_COMMIT_INSERT, POST_COMMIT_UPDATE, POST_COMMIT_DELETE using the following code within doWithApplicationContext:

```
    def sessionFactory = applicationContext.sessionFactory
    def serviceRegistry = sessionFactory.getServiceRegistry()
    EventListenerRegistry registry = serviceRegistry.getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);

    def listener = (SearchPersistenceListener)applicationContext.getBean("searchPersistenceListener") 

    def groupUpdate = registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_UPDATE)
    groupUpdate.prependListener((PostUpdateEventListener) listener)
    def groupInsert = registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_INSERT)
    groupInsert.prependListener((PostInsertEventListener) listener)
    def groupDelete = registry.getEventListenerGroup(EventType.POST_COMMIT_DELETE)
    groupDelete.prependListener((PostDeleteEventListener) listener)
```

We are in the process of upgrading from grails 2 to grails 3 and during the upgrade the update listener is no longer always called so for instance if I run the code below in a controller the listener will not by called:

```
    def object = Candidate.get(1)           
    if (object.lastName == "AAAAA")
        object.lastName = "ccccc"
    else
        object.lastName = "AAAAA"
    object.save(flush: true)
```

If I add Candidate.wthTransaction { } around the code block then it will work however it would be difficult to go through all the existing code to change it.

If the listener is attached to the POST_UPDATE event instead then this always gets fired so this is another option however using the existing listener code results in concurrent modification errors which appear to happen whenever createCriteria is used to retrieve data.

Is there some way to always trigger the post commit update event?

Comment: Just wondering why you wouldn't use the builtin domain event handlers beforeUpdate afterUpdate, in the domain object itself instead of poking around in serviceRegistry etc.?  Just curious.

Comment: The code was written a while ago. I did look into switching to use the grails afterUpdate event however the process above tracks some audit changes with before and after values and on the grails events I couldn't see an obvious way to retrieve the old state properties.